# Responsive JavaScript Menu Not Showing in Mobile View

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I implemented a navigation menu on [this website](https://alexandrachel.org/). While the menu works very well in desktop mode, it will not work in mobile viewing. I think there is an issue with connecting to the JavaScript - https://alexandrachel.org/scripts/script.js

The navigation menu should work like [this website](http://usher1f.org/)

How I can get the navigation menu in mobile viewing to work?

Comment: I should add that I am using the menu from CSS Menu Maker and followed this tutorial - http://cssmenumaker.com/br/blog/wordpress-3-drop-down-menu-tutorial

Comment: I have JQuery in the header - <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

Comment: Is there a different JQuery I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

Your whole site is not responsive, so either write [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to make it responsive , or else for minimal responsive you can use [bootstrap framework](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) which is lightweight and easy to use and for more responsive mobile menus also you can use [smart menus](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjk0fqz8t3YAhVLI5QKHawzBCgQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.smartmenus.org%2F&usg=AOvVaw22_b967QyOujfc2Wr84JwR) . So, its your choice either you write raw custom code or use the resources.

Comment: Please don't worry about the rest of the site not being responsive - I will correct that with media query. I'm more concerned about why the menu itself not working in responsive mode.

Comment: did you use any plugins for making it responsive ?

Comment: I used CSS Menu Maker to help me create the menu.

Comment: This is the specific menu I am using - http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/quartz-responsive-menu

Comment: i guess you are missing javascript files

Answer (score 0):

What the script does, is it changes the CSS for the small displays, so the menu is transformed to become a drop-down on handheld devices. However, the current problem is that the script cannot start, because it cannot find jQuery. And thus, on small displays, the CSS is incorrect and your menu is not visible (however it is there, and functional).

If you load your webpage over HTTPS (as in https://alexandrachel.org/), then the scripts and CSS files should also be requested via a secure protocol.

Try changing a request to jQuery to (note https://):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

And you can remove the second request of version `1.10.2` from `googleapis.com`, since you are already pulling the latest version from `jquery.com`.

Answer (score 0):

[Errors in loading your website ref: Chrome Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S19hu.png)

jQuery can't be found plus a lot of your content is being served over http whereas the main website loads on https so just fix those requests and import jQuery.
And this should work 
Ref: to the attached image for the errors